# Google Chrome Developer Tools Hitting Non-Existent Breakpoints

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having a lot of trouble with Google Chrome Developer Tools: it's hitting non-existent breakpoints. The below is just one example. As you can see, all breakpoints are on one source file, and Line 653 is not one of them. (There are no XHR or DOM breakpoints either). Why am I hitting this breakpoint? Sometimes it stops in HTML or JSP, too.

Are people actually using Chrome Developer Tools for serious JS debugging, or are they using something else?

[image]

Comment: Can you go to `chrome://version` and note your **Google Chrome**, **OS**, and **JavaScript** versions?

Comment: Google Chrome 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Revision 8f51ed0e633e109109762a3deb18a50e8c138819-refs/branch-heads/3239@{#643}
OS Windows
JavaScript V8 6.3.292.46
Flash 28.0.0.126